# Running 2 Flask apps on same port using Supervisord

Tags: flask, server, backend, gunicorn, supervisord

I have 2 separate Flask apps, mainapp and secondaryapp. However they both are using the same interface and the same port. So the command I use to run each one is:

```
  gunicorn mainapp:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
  gunicorn secondaryapp:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Secondaryapp is running through Nginx and needs to run on port 8000. I was initially running mainapp on port 80 but this wasn't working when I changed it to run on port 8000 the app ran, but now secondaryapp doesn't run and I get the error:

```
 2016-06-13 17:27:59,965 DEBG 'app' stderr output:
 2016-06-13 17:27:59 [34408] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 80)
```

How can I get the main and secondary apps to run at the same time?

In case it helps, the supervisord.conf file looks like:

```
[program:nginx]
command = service nginx start
autostart = True
[program:mainapp]
command = gunicorn mainapp:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
autostart = True
[program:secondaryapp]
command = gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 secondaryapp:app
autostart = True
directory = ...
```

Comment: You can't run two things on the some port. You'll need to run each app on its on own port and reflect that in your Nginx config.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish something similar with the supervisord fcgi server using program groups. Take a look at the supervisord docs: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#fcgi-program-x-section-settings

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341226/running-2-gunicorn-apps-and-nginx-with-supervisord

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running 2 Gunicorn Apps and Nginx with Supervisord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341226/running-2-gunicorn-apps-and-nginx-with-supervisord)