# Running 2 Gunicorn Apps and Nginx with Supervisord

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

This problem has admittedly stumped me for months. I've just procrastinated fixing other bugs and putting this aside until now where it HAS to be fixed --

I am trying to run 2 separate gunicorn apps and start nginx within the same supervisord.conf file. When I start supervisor, I am able to successfully run the handlecalls app but when I go to the website that commentbox is responsible for loading, I get an internal service error (500).

When I run the handlecalls and commentbox apps separately with the commands following the command field, the apps run fine. Why is the commentbox program giving me a 500 error when I try to run both with supervisord?

## my supervisord script:

```
[program:nginx]
directory = /var/www/vmail
command = service nginx start -g "daemon off;"
autostart = True

[program:commentbox]
directory = /var/www/vmail
command = gunicorn app:app -bind 0.0.0.0:8000
autostart = True

[program:handlecalls]
directory = /var/www/vmail
command = gunicorn handle_calls:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
autostart = True

[supervisord]
directory = /var/www/vmail
logfile = /var/www/vmail/supervisorerrs.log
loglevel = trace
```

Comment: You let both listen on port 8000?

Comment: Thanks. As an update, I changed the handle_calls command to gunicorn handle_calls:app --bind 0.0.0.0:80 and removed nginx from the script. Now the commentbox program will work but not handle calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with supervisord. Supervisord is just a way for you to start/stop/restart your server. This has more to do with your server's configuration.

The basic: To serve two gunicorn apps with nginx, you have to run them on two different ports, then config nginx to proxy_pass the request to their respective ports. The reson is: once a process is running on a port, that port cannot be used by another process.

So change the configuration in your supervisord script to:

```
[program:commentbox]
directory = /var/www/vmail
command = gunicorn app:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
autostart = True

[program:handlecalls]
directory = /var/www/vmail
command = gunicorn handle_calls:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8001
autostart = True
```

Then in your nginx server's configuration for `handlecalls`

```
proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8081
```

**Update: Here is the basics of deploying a web application**

1. As mentioned above, one port can only be listened by a process.
2. You can use nginx as a http server, listening to port `80` (or `443` for https), then passing the request to other applications listening to other ports (for example, `commentbox` on port `8000` and handlecalls on port `8001`)
3. You can add rules to nginx as how to serve your application by adding certain server configuration files in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` (by default. It is different in some cases). The rules should specify a way for nginx to know which application it should send the request to, for example:

   - To reuse the same http port (`80`), each application should be assigned to a different domain. i.e: `commentbox.yourdomain.com` for `commentbox` and `handlecalls.yourdomain.com` for `handlecalls`
   - A way to serve two different apps on the same domain, is for them to serve on different ports. For example: `yourdomain.com` would serve `commentbox` and `yourdomain.com:8080` would serve `handlecalls`
   - A way to serve two different apps on the same domain and the same ports, is for them to serve on two different endpoints. For example `yourdomain.com/commentbox` would serve `commentbox` and `yourdomain.com/handlecalls` would serve `handlecalls`
4. After adding configuration files to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`, you must symlink those files to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, well, to tell nginx that you want to enable them. You can add the files directly to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, but I don't recommend it, since it doesn't give you a convenient way to enable/disable your application.

**Update: Here is how to config nginx to serve gunicorn applications using two different subdomains:**

1. Add two subdomains `commentbox.yourdomain.com` and `handlecalls.yourdomain.com`, and point them both to your server's IP.
2. Create a a configuration file for `commentbox` at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/commentbox` with the following content (edit as fit):

   ```
   server {
       listen 80; 

       server_name           commentbox.yourdomain.com;

       root                  /path/to/your/application/static/folder;    
       location / {
           try_files         $uri @app;
       }

       location @app {
           proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
           proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

           proxy_redirect     off;
           proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a configuration file for `handlecalls` at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/handlecalls` with the following content (edit as fit):

   ```
   server {
       listen 80; 

       server_name           handlecalls.yourdomain.com;

       root                  /path/to/your/application/static/folder;    
       location / {
           try_files         $uri @app;
       }

       location @app {
           proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
           proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

           proxy_redirect     off;
           proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8001;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create symlinks to enable those servers:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/commentbox /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
   sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/handlecalls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
   ```
5. Restart nginx to take effect

   ```
   sudo service nginx restart
   ```

Comment: Thanks. As an update, I changed the handle_calls command to gunicorn handle_calls:app --bind 0.0.0.0:80 and removed nginx from the script. Now the commentbox program will work but not handle calls. But nginx has serveral configuration files. In the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory, I see default.conf, ssl,conf, and virtual.conf. Which one do I add the proxy_pass line to?

Comment: @user3831464 Err, so you just installed nginx without configuring it to serve those servers?

Comment: @user3831464 I have added a guide on configuring nginx

Comment: Thank you very much!! This helps me understand nginx a lot more. Will give it a try.

Comment: Hi @btquanto, unfortunately this did not solve my issue. The apps are still not running but it may help someone else so sure.

Comment: @user3831464 try running your apps manually in two different sessions first before using supervisord, then check the log if there are any errors

Comment: I can run the app for handlecalls manually using 'gunicorn handle_calls:app --bind 0.0.0.0:80' and commentbox manually using 'gunicorn app:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000' but not on 8001. I tried setting the proxy pass to these ports but neither app runs.

Comment: You shouldn't bind to port 80, else nginx cannot listen to it, which would result in nginx failing to start. If you cannot use port 8001, then try 8002, or 8080, 8081... just remember to reconfig proxy_pass to those ports, and restart nginx. You can look for my username on Skype, if you want direct help

Comment: Thanks! It turns out I had to request port 8001 be opened since my org manages my server permissions. I should have checked that first. Would have saved a lot of headache. Will try again once they open the ports.

Comment: UPDATE: I didn't use sites-available/enabled/symlinks at all. instead I updated the supervisord conf file to run on 8001 for handle_calls and 8000 for commentbox. I then updated the link URL pointing to the handle_calls code to mydomain:8001 and everything worked.

Comment: I am not seeing any gunicorn configuration

Comment: @Alvar The problem in the original question was caused by two gunicorn processes running on the same port (`8000`). You can set the port in a config file, but the OP set the port directly as a parameter. In the answer, I changed the ports by changing the `--bind` parameter in the `gunicorn` command.

Comment: the gunicor command you mean the proxy_pass?  I have tried for days to install a pgadmin4 on my web in a subdirectory like this www.myweb.com/pgadmin4. I could add an extra location in my nginx file but then I have awful troubles adding another unix:command in my gunicorn_start file. it would always give badgateway 502 and this is because nginx can't communicate with gunicorn when it comes to reaching that subdirectory. should I create two different gunicorn files?

Comment: @Alvar The gunicorn command was specified in the supervisord config file. Specifically, `gunicorn app:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`.

In your case, your web should be running on one port, and `pgadmin4` would be running on another port.

Your nginx config should also add a location `/pgadmin4`, and proxypass incoming traffic to the port `pgadmin4` is running. Some rewrite rules would also be needed, else `pgadmin4` would be serving some `/pgadmin4/<path>` that it doesn't understand.

Comment: I have got the whole thing here :/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77750477/exporting-a-postgresql-backup-from-my-local-pgadmin-into-my-postgresql-dabase-in