# exporting a postgresql backup from my local pgadmin into my postgresql dabase in ubuntu vps server

Tags: django, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I very much preferred to have a subdirectory for my pgadmin4 like myweb.com/pgadmin4 but  could not have it the right way. I already had my gunicorn_start file which showed me the web fine, but when I tried to reach that subdirectory it was always badgateway 502. I was just adding another binding command in here below,
first this is a file

```
SOCKFILE=/home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock

exec ../venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \  <-------TRYING TO ADD ANOTHER unix: for pgadmin
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --log-file=
```

And of course, I had created another location in my nginx file like this:

```
  location /pgadmin4/ {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock;
    proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin4;
}
```

It wouldn't work (probably because in my gunicorn_start file I didn't know what syntax to write)
Something like this?

```
--bind unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock --workers=13 --threads=25 --chdir ~/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgadmin4 pgAdmin4:app
```

I yes managed to launch that subdirectory by using an artificial command like this:

```
gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock --workers=13 --threads=25 --chdir ~/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgadmin4 pgAdmin4:app
```

I say artificial because it is a one-off launch, it is not in the gunicorn_start file restarted by supervisor and when I entered the subdirectory, all I had was a blank page with some error messages. That messed up completely my web, I could not reach it at all, not even the root domain, so I completely deleted my server and started all over again.

, so I went to my local pgadmin4 I made a backup file.sql and exported that file to my server. Then I tried to import it in my server using a psql command. My database has 3 tables that are not created by the models (unmanaged) because they refer to a database of countries, regions and cities. So, I don't know why, either they are not backed-up or not imported, but when I checked to see the list of tables imported, these 3 tables were not preseent, which is very bad as I absolutely need those tables. I would prefer to go the pgadmin4 way for any future changes I may need to do, as the shell is totally an unfriendly environment.

Any expertise on how to go about with this?

-